# Float interval intersection

Tags: python

I have two rectangles. I need to see if/where they overlap.

Method 1: 
1)Take domain and range of each one individually.
2) Use a formula akin to the math formula:

```
x1 < a < x2
```

I wrote this in Python as:

```
if x1[0] > x2[0] and x1[0] < x2[1] or x1[1] > x2[0] and x1[1] < x2[1]: return True
```

The problem:
This is supposed to detect any over lap, it does this by comparing boundaries. However it assumes that that boundary points of x1 will be in x2. If the boundaries of x1[0],x1[1] though are larger than x2[0][1], than it will return false which would indicate there is no overlap, when in reality the ranges the intervals between the two points would be intersecting.

Method 2:
Use set() data type and its built-in functions:

```
   def containsRectangle(self,Rectangle):
        x1 = range(self.x_interval[0],self.x_interval[1])
        x2 = range(Rectangle.x_interval[0],Rectangle.x_interval[1])
        set_x1 = set(x1)
        set_x2 = set(x2)
        if set_x1.intersection(x2):
            return True
```

The problem:
I must be using floating point numbers because I need precision for my calculations. Python does not allow me to iterate over floats.

I'm all out of ideas guys. Any help would be greatly appreciated mates!

Comment: What coordinates do you have? Two per rectangle?

Comment: Also see https://wiki.python.org/moin/PointsAndRectangles

Comment: r2 = Rectangle2D(0,0,10,10)
r1 = Rectangle2D(2,2,2,4)

Thnx for the article

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, your second method is correct. However, at some level, you have to have discrete values in the set. If you'd like continuous, then comparing the extremeties of the intersection will work, as you've done in your first example.

Having established that the intersection of 2 rectangles is a polygon, you can use any [points inside polygon](http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html) approach:

```
def point_inside_polygon(x,y,poly):
    """ Assume poly is the intersection of the two rectangles and (x,y) is the point to check 
    """
    n = len(poly)
    inside =False

    p1x,p1y = poly[0]
    for i in range(n+1):
        p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y,p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xinters = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y
    return inside
```

Comment: I think this would be easier if I broke it down into two different functions. One that detects if a rectangle is inside another one, and another rectangle which checks if there is overlap between the two(meaning one boundary is within another and the other boundary is outside it).

We can call these:
contains(Rectangle)
overlaps(Rectangle)

With this being the case, which function would my second method fullfill and which one would the points inside polygon approach fullfill?

Comment: The intersection of your rectangles will be the same as the boundaries of the smaller one if one is entirely contained within the other. At that point, you'd just need to check if the point in question lies in the smaller rectangle.